# How can I install an extension so that all users can access it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Installing extensions in the last few versions of Visual Studio seems easy. However, as far as I understand, they are only installed for the user running the program.

How can an administrator install an extension system-wide so that it is available to all users in Visual Studio?

I'm aware that a small portion of extensions are provided as installers that install the extensions for all users, however, most extensions seem to be provided as VSIX files.

Comment: You should mark this as answered

Answer (score 23):

VSIXInstaller.exe has the **/admin** switch that should install an extension for all users.

You can to find and download the needed extension on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ and call the VSIXInstaller.exe.
For example:

```
VSIXInstaller.exe /admin path_to_the_vsix.vsix
```

Comment: For me VSIXInstaller was located at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` (VS2015).

Comment: as of December 2020 I have a `~/.config/Code/CachedExtensionVSIXs/` folder on my rather fresh installed Ubuntu machine(!) – so possibly VSIX got integrated into vscode?