# Share Visual Studio Extensions

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to easily share Visual Studio extensions on the same machine?

I have a normal profile and an admin profile (which can install executables). This means that I have a bunch of extensions if I run Visual Studio as myself and a different set if I run as my admin account.

I can see the extensions get installed here which is obviously profile based:

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174656/how-can-i-install-an-extension-so-that-all-users-can-access-it

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like I need to download the VSIX first?

Comment: Yes, you need to download the VSIX first.