# If I want to use an extension run with a different account in Visual Studio 2019, do I really need to download and install it all over again?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I downloaded and installed an extension to my copy of VS 2019, but then found that I needed to use a different user account to access a server somewhere...so I started it with:

```
runas /user:thedomain\theuser /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

And when my window displayed I found my extension was no longer listed in the list of the installed.

And so I had to re-download/install all 300+ MBs of it again.

This sounds a bit mad.  What if I have 100+ different accounts that I need to connect with?  Do I need 30GBs of space for this single plugin for each of those accounts?  And do I have to install it manually each time?

Comment: Would running the command with `/noprofile` help?

Comment: Oh, and did I mention that the installer runs as me?

Comment: Or is it on a per-project basis?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174656/how-can-i-install-an-extension-so-that-all-users-can-access-it

Comment: @leeand00 Hi friend, any update for this issue? Can Sergey's or Perry's answer helps to resolve your issue? If it still blocks you, feel free to let us know:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT well I went back and ran it again as admin account, and this the the extensions were just there; I didn’t have to re-install them like I did before.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I have 100+ different accounts that I need to connect with? Do
>   I need 30GBs of space for this single plugin for each of those
>   accounts? And do I have to install it manually each time?

As far as l know, VS extensions are **per-user** and are installed in the `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Visual Studio version>\Extensions\` folder.

A few extensions are administrative extensions and are installed in the `<Visual Studio>installation folder>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\` folder. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019#per-user-and-administrative-extensions). So when you change an account for Windows, extensions from your previous account will not be loaded in the current Visual Studio.

**However**, **VSIXInstaller.exe** has a switch that installs extensions for all users on the current system just as Sergey said and thanks for him. You no longer have to re-download the extensions for each account.

**Solution**

1.First, you should download the extension which you need from the [VS Marketplace website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/)

2.Call the **VSIXInstaller.exe** in cmd which exists in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE` in my side.Then run this command below:

```
VSIXInstaller.exe /admin  xxxx.vsix(object name)
```

It will install the extension into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions`(like a public extension library) so that all users can access to it.

**Edit**:

If you have installed them before, you did not have to reinstall them again. Just run VS as Administrator and then you can access them again.

Hope it could help you:)